# Cantidad de conexiones y cantidad de Instancias en un script php/mysql

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, singleton

En estos últimos día eh tenido un problema con un script en un servidor, el cuál me bloquea el sitio por "max_user_connections limit exceeded".
Pregunto si estoy en lo correcto:

- Investigando un poco y aplicando el patrón Singleton al objeto de conexión me creará solo una instancia de conexión para todas las peticiones, ahí creo que optimizaría la cantidad que se hacen simultáneamente, es asi?
- Ahora como es un sitio amplio y tengo 5 o 6 clases con sus respectivos métodos, aplica igual el Singleton para todas las instancias que se crean de distintos metodos de varias clases?, por cierto tengo muchas instancias en ciertas páginas. No esto muy seguro de este tema para una mejor optimización:

Mi clase de Conexion.php :

```
<?php   

class Conexion 
{ 
  

    public $db;     
    private static $dns = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=notibaires"; 
    private static $user = "root"; 
    private static $pass = "";     
    private static $instance;

    public function __construct ()  
    {        
       $this->db = new PDO(self::$dns,self::$user,self::$pass);       
    } 

    public static function getInstance()
    { 
        if(!isset(self::$instance)) 
        { 
            $object= __CLASS__; 
            self::$instance=new $object; 
            var_dump('conexion creada<br>');

        } 
        var_dump('instancia creada<br>');

        return self::$instance; 
    }   

}
```

Aplicado en otra clase (new_models.php)

```
    <?php
        require_once "Conexion.php";
       
        class Noticias
        { 
    
    
            public function __construct(){
                        
                         $this->porta = array();
    
              }
            
               
    
                public function get_portada($posicion,$lim1,$lim2){
    
                        $cce = Conexion::getInstance(); 
                        
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias where posicion = :posicion AND fechahora <= now() ORDER BY orden ASC,fecha desc,id_nota desc LIMIT :lim1, :lim2";
                        $sentencia = $cce->db->prepare($sql);
                        $sentencia->bindParam(':posicion', $posicion, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentencia->bindParam(':lim1', $lim1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentencia->bindParam(':lim2', $lim2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $sentencia->execute();
    
                        while ($fila = $sentencia->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                             $this->porta[] = $fila;
                         }
    
                         $ret_porta = $this->porta;
                         return ( $ret_porta ) ? $ret_porta : 0;
                         
                         $sentencia->closeCursor();
                         $sentencia=null;
                        
                        
                }

...más métodos
```

Controlador que genera instancias de distintas clases:

```
      $men = new Varios(); //menu princ
      $arreglo = $men->get_menu('1','1');
      
      $men = new Varios(); // menu princ en < 640
      $arreglo = $men->get_menu('1','1');

      $men1 = new Varios(); // mas secciones
      $arreglo1 = $men1->get_menu('1','0');
      
      $menult = new Noticias(); // ultimas notas c foto
      $ultima = $menult->get_notasUltimas(4);
      
      
      $menclim = new Varios(); /// clima gde
      $menclima = $menclim->get_climaGde();
        
    
      $quesecc = new Noticias(); 
      $quesuple = new Varios(); 
      $quesubsec = new Noticias();
     
      $cuadvid = new Varios(); 
      $matCuadroVideo = $cuadvid->VideosTapa();
```

en definitiva, la sugerencia que me puedan brindar sería:

- Este es un camino correcto para una optimización de conexiones?
- No afecta la cantidad de instancias a los recursos y/o rendimiento del sitio ?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿No notaste la mejora con tu implementación de singleton? Para cada cliente es suficiente una conexión ¿el número de clientes supera el máximo de conexiones?. Por cierto, puedes mover el `new PDO` a donde tienes `new $object`.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte Sal, perdón no entendí eso de mover el new PDO ...

Answer (score 1):

1.- Si creas un singleton este estará vivo en el hilo de conexión entre el cliente-servidor. Si la persona ingresa al sitio desde otro navegador o es un usuario totalmente distinto se generará un hilo de conexión nuevo y por ende una nueva instancia de tu singleton.
En php dicho patrón generalmente es soportado por variables estáticas, por lo cual, no es un objeto persistente y muere con el respectivo hilo de conexión. Si quieres mantener tu singleton al recargar la pagina por ejemplo, te recomiendo pensar en almacenar dicha instancia en una variable de sesión, caché o alguna estrategia similar de almacenamiento.

2.- Depende exclusivamente de la forma en que trabajes la conexión a la base de datos, si cada clase abrirá su conexión a la db y estás generando N instancias de esa clase, entonces tendrás N instancias de la conexión. Sin duda es un problema si tienes 50000 instancias de esa clase, ya que indirectamente tendrás 50000 conexiones que hacen absolutamente lo mismo.

En la practica lo mejor seria tener una sola conexión que pueda ser reutilizada por todos los objetos. Esto depende exclusivamente del diseño de la solución, pero lo importante es tener una sola conexión a la base de datos por cada hilo de conexión.

Lo más simple y utilizado es que tu conexión quede declarada en un objeto global y un archivo separado del resto de la lógica, para luego llamar ese objeto global en un apartado principal de tu aplicación (o en múltiples lados pero con [require_once()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php)) y que así dicha variable esté disponible en tu respectiva clase y por ende en todas tus instancias de clase. Otra alternativa es pasar la conexión como un parámetro a cada instancia de clase, pero esto ensucia un poco el código y dificulta la mantenibilidad a largo plazo (Esto ultimo es subjetivo bajo mi percepción, pero igual es una alternativa valida).

> Ahora, lo más importante es que no estés cometiendo el famoso problema de N+1

En resumen el problema N+1 se da cuando traes una cantidad de registros, luego iteras esa cantidad de registros y ejecutas otra consulta para cada registro. Esto se soluciona simplemente haciendo los respectivos joins en la base de datos para traer todo en 1 consulta y luego estructurar los objetos en php.

**Ejemplo de N+1**

Si quieres obtener los usuarios y sus mascotas lo ideal seria hacer un select con un join de las supuestas tablas, usuarios y mascotas. En la practica esto equivale a 1 select.

Se producirá N+1 si primero haces un select por los usuarios y luego iterás los usuarios y haces un select por las mascotas de dicho usuario. Si tienes 100 usuarios, estarias haciendo 101 consultas a la base de datos, sin duda la estás matando.

Si volvemos a tu error, el `max_user_connections` puede estar siendo provocado por la cantidad de instancias de clase que estás manejando (suponiendo que cada clase maneja su propia conexión a la db) o si tienes el problema de N+1 en alguna parte de tu aplicación (que al final también se produce si cada instancia de clase tiene su propia conexión a la db).

Desde luego que también puedes [aumentar las conexiones por usuario](https://qastack.mx/dba/47131/how-to-get-rid-of-maximum-user-connections-error), pero puede llegar a ser un problema de rendimiento enorme y costoso a futuro si no comprendes bien que está sucediendo ahora.

PD: Quise abordar la pregunta desde un punto de vista más teórico, porque la forma en que implementes la conexión a la db dependerá exclusivamente del diseño de la solución, no hay un estándar o formula mágica para ello.

Comment: Gracias Cesar por el aporte y el gran desarrollo del mismo.
Mi pregunta es como manejar la cantidad de instancias si de esto depende el rendimiento del sitio, ya que necesito muchas para varias tareas. 
Ej en un diario digital, necesito mostrar módulos con distintas caracteristicas. Ultima notas, deportes, policiales, etc. El cual debo hacer una instancia para un método de cada tarea o compartir un mismo método pero con distintos parametros de respuesta. "Es normal" tener en un sitio gran cantidad de instancias, esa es mi cuestión (aparte de optimizar consultas por suspuesto).

Comment: Es un caso bastante extenso de abordar por la cantidad de aristas, el problema que presentas en particular realmente no es la cantidad de instancia de clase (PHP), si no que todas tengan su inicialización propia de la DB o estén haciendo N+1, generando así un desbordamiento del limite de conexiones definidas en la DB.
Para tu caso, mi recomendación es que utilices algún framework de php como: Laravel, Lumen, Zend o Symfony que ya tienen estructurado todo esto y te permitirán enfocarte solo en el desarrollo y limitarán las malas practicas.